# Moment.js trouble converting unix to local time to utc

Tags: javascript, momentjs

Hi I am having trouble converting a timestamp from unix to local to ultimately utc.

```
let convertToUTC = (unixTimestamp)=> {

let convertedUnixToLocal = moment.unix(unixTimestamp).format("MM/DD/YYYY HH:mm:ss");
let UTC = moment.utc(convertedUnixToLocal).format("MM/DD/YYYY");

return UTC;
}
```

For example I am expecting

`convertToUTC(1594439125) //Actually Returns 07/10/2020 Expecting 07/11/2020 -` This one was wrong

`convertToUTC(1594393827) //Actually Returns 07/10/2020 Expecting 07/10/2020 -` This one was ok

I'm not sure what exactly I am doing wrong?

Comment: Both numbers convert to Jan 19, 1970. Are you sure you have the right number?

Comment: Ok, got it, you've omitted the zeroes...

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the `.format()` part in your `convertToUTC ...` line.
I am not exactly sure why, but a formatted moment date doesn't parse again.
So:

```
let convertToUTC = (unixTimestamp)=> {

let convertedUnixToLocal = moment.unix(unixTimestamp);
let UTC = moment.utc(convertedUnixToLocal).format("MM/DD/YYYY");

return UTC;
}
```

Works as expected.

P.S. After some more digging, it seems that the problem is the specific format that you are using in the `moment.unix(unixTimestamp)` function, as `moment.unix(unixTimestamp).format()` (default formatting) works just fine.